# How can I identify all nodes whose name begins with "square" and ends with a number like "square1", "square2", etc inside of a child nodes with name?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsstring

I want to find all of the child nodes whose names begin with a certain text. I wanted to do it without writing hasPrefix, I thought there was a shorthand way for this. Something along the lines of

```
let someSquare = SKShapeNode()
someSquare.name = "square1"

let someOtherSquare = SKShapeNode()
someOtherSquare.name = "square2"

self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "@%square") { stop, in
    
}
```

So the actual question I guess should be about that shorthand Objective-C NSString syntax or whatever for strings. I'm not sure what to call it. "@%square" or "%@square"? I remember seeing this somewhere, is this correct syntax?

Comment: Are you thinking about the `%@` format specifier used for string formatting (which is available in Swift, as well as Objective-C)? That would have nothing to do with the task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i appreciate it, I haven't done a lot of work with Strings. I think what I may have been thinking about was syntax for NSPredicates or NSSortDescriptors in core data filtering, I thought it could have been a faster solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SpriteKit documentation includes the page [Searching the Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/searching_the_node_tree). It shows a syntax for advanced searches.

If I'm reading that documentation correctly, you simply need:

```swift
self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "square[1-9]") { stop, in
    
}
```

This will match nodes with names "square1", "square2", ..., "square9".

Comment: I just found this accidentally in the enumerateChildNodes definition

   ` /**
     * Simplified shorthand for enumerateChildNodesWithName that returns an array of the matching nodes.
     * This allows subscripting of the form:
     *      NSArray *childrenMatchingName = node[@"name"]
     *
     * or even complex like:
     *      NSArray *siblingsBeginningWithA = node[@"../a*"]
     *
     * @param name An Xpath style path that can include simple regular expressions for matching node names.`

Comment: @quickj Yes, that syntax is described in the link I put in my answer.

Comment: the link you put in your answer shows "some useful search strings to help get you started" but "that syntax" is not described in it, specifically *siblingsBeginningWithA = node[@"../a"] Your answer still solves the problem a lot simpler, but I'm still curious about this syntax

Comment: Did you scroll down to the [Use an Advanced Search](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/searching_the_node_tree#1968653) section of that page?

Comment: yes it doesn't really get into that, or if it does then it has gone over my head, because it isn't explicitly describing  how [@"../a] works, its inside the brackets, the link mentions the .. part, and the / part seperately so im missing how to use it all combined i guess